Why does the compiler allow me to add an object of type Pair<String, String> to the Pair<String,Integer> list?
I'm using the Pair class to store information about stadiums, i.e. name of the stadium and its capacity.
Let's look at the first example. I create a list and fill it with instances of parameterized type Pair<String, Integer>(lines 1,2).If I explicitly create an instance of another parameterized type Pair<String, String>(line3), store it in a variable and try to add it to the list, the compiler throws an error, i.e. everything is as it should be(line 4). But if I remove lines 2,3 and create instance of Pair<String, String> directly in the add method(Second example)  then the program is compiled and executed. Can anyone explain why the compiler did not throw an error?
first example(works as expected)
      List<Pair<String, Integer>> stadiums = new ArrayList<>();
1.    stadiums.add( new Pair("Bridgeforth Stadium", 25000));
2.    stadiums.add( new Pair("Michigan Stadium", 109901));

3.    Pair<String, String> stringPair =  new Pair("Lane Stadium", "some str value");
4.    stadiums.add(stringPair); // **Required type:Pair<String,Integer> Provided:Pair<String,String>**



second example(something wrong)
     List<Pair<String, Integer>> stadiums = new ArrayList<>();
     1. stadiums.add( new Pair("Bridgeforth Stadium", 25000));
     2. stadiums.add( new Pair("Michigan Stadium", 109901));

     5.    stadiums.add( new Pair("Lane Stadium", "some str value"));


It seems to me that I need to create a variable of a parameterized type (as I indicated above) in order for the compiler to work correctly. But I would like to understand why this is so.

Also see What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?

A better practice than using the Pair class would be creating your own record class, for instance public record Stadium(String name, int capacity) { }.  Nice and short, and automatically creates name() and capacity() methods, along with equals, hashCode, and toString methods.

When you compile your code -- any of its versions -- you will get an unchecked type warning that tells you that you are doing something dangerous that might result in type errors.  Guess what?  That's happening.
The correct version of your code is always to write
stadiums.add(new Pair<>("Lane Stadium", "some str value"));

with the <>.  Without the <>, you are telling the compiler not to worry exactly what type the Pair is, and it is faithfully carrying out your instructions not to worry.
If you have a generic type, a type defined with <...> like class Pair<A, B>, then essentially every time you ever refer to Pair, it should be Pair<something, something>.  (The handful of exceptions include Pair.class and import foo.bar.Pair;.)

A note that this is for backwards compatibility, early Java didn't have generics so Pair was always implicitly Pair<Object, Object>.
